Why the graph of morphism is a closed subvariety?
I am reading Fulton's book on Algebraic Curves. It is stated in Section 6.4, Proposition 8 that the graph $G(f)$ of morphism $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a closed subvariety in $X \times Y$. (Here $X, Y$ are varieties, but according to the book, they belong to the set of 'quasi-projective variety', if more general varieties are considered) It seems that every proof of this that I can find, including the proof in Fulton's book, only proves $G(f)$ is closed (as the preimage of $\Delta_Y$ for $(f \times id)$). But I do not understand why $G(f)$ is irreducible? I can prove the case when $X, Y$ are both affine variety since then the map $x \mapsto (x, f(x))$ will be a polynomial map $X \rightarrow X \times Y$. Then the irreducibility of $X$ corresponds to the irreducibility of $G(f)$. But what happens when $X, Y$ not affine?
Edit: Now I understand what went wrong. We only need the continuity of $\phi: x \mapsto (x, f(x))$ to prove $G(f)$ is irreducible. (At first I thought that we need $\phi$ to be a closed map so the polynomial case is easier to prove) Consider $\phi$ as a morphism $X \rightarrow X \times Y$. If $G(f)$ is reducible, namely $G(f) = Z_1 \cup Z_2$ where $Z_1, Z_2$ are proper closed subset of $G(f)$, then they are closed set of $X \times Y$. By continuity of $\phi$, $\phi^{-1}(Z_i)$ are closed. Since $\phi$ is onto $G(f)$, $\phi^{-1}(Z_i)$ are proper subset of $X$, which implies $X$ is reducible, a contradiction.

It's the same, $x \mapsto (x, f(x))$ is an isomorphism $X \cong G(f)$.

@QiaochuYuan But for something to be an isomorphism, shouldn't we first prove $G(f)$ is a variety? I mean, the morphism are defined on varieties, right?

You said you already know that $G(f)$ is closed, so what is the issue? It's a variety except that it is possibly reducible, and since it's isomorphic to $X$ it's irreducible.

@QiaochuYuan Thanks for the reply. Maybe it's the definition, on Fulton's book, morphisms are only defined for varieties. So to say something is a morphism, we should at first prove the domain and codomain are variety. But I think I understand what went wrong. (See the edits of my question) Thanks for the help!
